# Do different weapons have different base attack speeds?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I tried out a short bow ranger build in sPVP yesterday and noticed that it shoots faster than the longbow i usually use in PVE and WvWvW.

Do different weapons have different base attack speeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda.

The thing to remember is that it's not the weapons that matter, but the abilities of the profession who is using them.

The Axe in the hands of a necromancer is a fast weapon. In the hands of a Warrior, it's a bit slower.

Each ability has an effective "Cast" or animation time that doesn't change depending on the weapon you wield (though you can really only see this with utilities), and since there is no auto-attack (just abilities that, again, have a certain cast time), Guild Wars 2 has no real concept of attack speed.

The only way to make things happen faster, is to acquire the Quickness boon.